# fixing OAuthException in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am working with facebook graph API and I found this error. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid="myid",
    "type": OAuthException,
    "code": 803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the

```
/fql?q={your_urlencoded_query}&access_token={your_access_token}
```

endpoint? The query itself works fine with my own user_id...

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Comment: sry I didn't notice.. may have happened due to mistake